# IE: jQuery click listener fires on parent of disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

Is there a way to prevent firing of jQuery .click() listener on parent of button that is disabled?
e.g in this case:

```
<div>
  <button disabled="disabled">click me</button>
</div>
<script>
  // unfortunately this click handler is placed by 3rd party
  // library and I can't edit it. Just add another handlers or css
  $('div').on('click', function () {
    alert('div is still clickable, probable you use IE');
  });
</script>
```

In my project click event is placed with third-party library so I can't enable/disable itself or move binding to button.

**ADD**: I've found solution with not disabling the button, but proving it a "disabled" class, and adding event listener:

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

but what about disabled button? Is there a way to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
$('button').not(':disabled').parent().on('click',function(){});
```

You CAN remove the third-party click event and rebind them all on the page this way also with `.off()` or `unbind()`

```
$('div').unbind(); //or .off() depending on how the third-party set the handler
//then add your own click method after the unbinding.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('div').on('click', function (event) {
        if ($(this).find('button').is(':disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this new event listener is called after that is already attached, so it would not prevent call of alert();